Fix text anti-aliased by MS Paint
I'm trying to update a chart which has an 8-bit style but was imported to ms paint at some point. I like the overall layout of what's there so far, but a lot of the text got anti-aliased:


I have the original text for some but not all of the chart, as there is an even older version which did not get anti-aliased:

Is there a tool that I can use to correct the text of the chart, bringing it back in line with the original 8-bit style? I would like to continue from the second chart.
If possible, I would like to use gimp since that's what I already have installed, but I'm not particularly experienced with any image editing program so if you want me to install something different that's fine.

The top image seems to have Windows Clear Type anti-aliasing. This has nothing really to do with MS Paint. It was probably taken from a screenshot on a Windows PC.
In GIMP, the easiest way to fix it is probably to do a Threshold adjustment and adjust the slider, but you will lose all the colours. The colours could easily be added back afterwards on a new layer, with the blend mode set to Multiply
An example

As for the second image, just do the text at the top. There's nothing wrong with the colour portion.  You can make a selection using the rectangle select tool before applying a Threshold adjustment.

yes, the bottom of the second image is good; I wanted to include it in case it mattered that the full image wasn't evenly anti-aliased, if that even means anything. I'll mark as accepted later when I get back tonight if it works for me ^^
